# oracle trim data in a table col

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that Oracle has the `TRIM` function and I would like to use it to trim the whitespace out of a field in one of my tables.

As such:

```
update THIRD_PARTY_ADRS_INFO_TEMP
set HOUSE_NO = TRIM(HOUSE_NO);
```

just hangs when i try to run it in SQL Developer.

I have also tried `TRIM(' ' from HOUSE_NO)` and `REPLACE(HOUSE_NO,' ','')` all with the same effect

This seems like it should be really simple...

ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it "hangs" then this suggests that your session is blocked by another session.  You are trying to update every row in the table; if another session has locked a row in the same table and not yet committed your session will have to wait.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this was the issue. I restarted SQL developer and it worked...

Comment: even though the trim didn't actually remove all the white space... I must have some tabs in there or something...

Comment: I'd add a "WHERE HOUSE_NO != TRIM(HOUSE_NO)" clause to prevent wasting time on unnecessary updates

Comment: You have to be careful, in SQL Developer (as in several other products) it is possible to run some DML in the "main session", then if you click on the "Run SQL" button it runs it in a new session - causing you to block against yourself. I've gotten into the habit of hitting the Rollback button before clicking on the "Run SQL" button.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you solved the row lock. As to removing all sorts of blank space, you can also look into REGEXP_REPLACE if on a recent Oracle version. It is a bit slower than trim, but if you have multiple possible non-printing characters to deal with it might be worth a look.

e.g.

```
select regexp_replace(x,'[[:space:]|[:blank:]|[:cntrl:]]*$','')
   from (select 'ad f cde  '||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(8)||' ' as x from dual);
```

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer which relates to "oracle trim".  I got to this page because I searched on "oracle trim".  The accepted answer helped the OP, but will probably not help anyone else who finds this page.  This answer was most helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

How many rows in your table? You could try just doing a select rather than an update (with rownum < 10 for example) just to satisfy yourself that it's working.

Comment: And if your table is huge, try creating an index on the column HOUSE_NO.

Comment: Although he's updating every row, so an index may not help?

Comment: Adding an index on HOUSE_NO would also mean that every entry in that index would need the change reflected in it.